# How to pass user object to forms in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, view

How would I pass a user object or a request to my form for using it as an initial value for input textbox?

For example, I have my form:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
contact_name = forms.CharField(required=True, initial="???")
contact_email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
subjects = forms.ChoiceField(choices=emailsubjects)
content = forms.CharField(
    required=True,
    widget=forms.Textarea
)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = kwargs.pop("request")
    super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['contact_name'].label = "Your name:"
    self.fields['contact_email'].label = "Your email:"
    self.fields['content'].label = "What do you want to say?"
    self.fields['subjects'].label = "Please, select the subject of your message"
```

Where i want my user.first_name to be as a default value for contact_name field.

Here is my views.py, where i call for form:

```
def ContactsView(request):
form_class = ContactForm(request=request)
# new logic!
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = form_class(data=request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        contact_name = request.POST.get(
            'contact_name'
            , '')
        contact_email = request.POST.get(
            'contact_email'
            , '')
        form_content = request.POST.get('content', '')
        subjects = form.cleaned_data['subjects']
        subjects = dict(form.fields['subjects'].choices)[subjects]
        # Email the profile with the
        # contact information
        template = get_template('threeD/email/contact_template.txt')
        context = Context({
            'contact_name': contact_name,
            'subjects': subjects,
            'contact_email': contact_email,
            'form_content': form_content,
        })
        content = template.render(context)

        email = EmailMessage(
            "New message from " + contact_name,
            content,
            "Message - " + subjects + ' ',
            ['smart.3d.printing.facility@gmail.com'],
            headers={'Reply-To': contact_email}
        )
        email.send()
        messages.success(request, "Thank you for your message.")
        return redirect('/index/contacts/')


return render(request, 'threeD/contacts.html', {
    'form': form_class,
})
```

Any help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have changed your form to take the request object. Therefore you can access `self.request.user` inside your form's methods:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop("request")
        super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['contact_name'].label = "Your name:"
        self.fields['contact_name'].initial = self.request.user.first_name
```

You also have to update your view to pass the request object. Remember to update the code for GET and POST requests.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ContactForm(data=request.POST, request=request)
    ...
else:
    # GET request
    form = ContactForm(request=request)
```

Finally, by passing the request to the form, you have tightly coupled it to the view. It might be better to pass the `user` to the form instead. This would make it easier to test the form separately from the view. If you change the form, remember to update the view as well.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much for helping me out! It works! 
One thing i also had to do in my views was:
    form_class = ContactForm(request=request)
    # new logic!
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(data=request.POST, request = request)
I had to change form = ContactFrom(...) instead if what i had before. Don't really get why, but it works now :/ :D

Comment: That's because of a mistake in the first line of the view - it should be `form_class = ContactForm`. For a function based view like this, I think it's clearer to remove that line completely, and use `form = ContactForm(data=request.POST, request = request` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the initial values in the view:

**views:**

```
def ContactsView(request):
    form_class = ContactForm(request=request,
                             initial={'contact_name': request.user.first_name})
    ...
```